# OSX update problem

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [os x update problem](https://superuser.com/questions/281444/os-x-update-problem)

I have installed OS X  10.6.3 on my Vaio.  It's working somehow fine, sufficient to learn iPhone app development, but whenever I try to update it, after restarting it hangs for a long time. Scroll keeps on moving.  I checked for more than 4 hours.  Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You've installed OS X on non-Apple hardware and you wonder why it doesn't work?

The answer is simple: buy a Mac.